# DataTables column data property containing brackets

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables version 1.10.12  from https://datatables.net/

Follow an example:

Columns:

```
columns: [
    {title: "Id", data: "id"},
    {title: "Name", data: "Person[name]"},
    {title: "Gender", data: "Person[gender]"},
]
```

Data

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "Person[name]":"Foo Bar",
    "Person[gender]":"M"
}]
```

The result of this grid will render only `id` field, how can I use brackets as key values?

Comment: could you explain more , what exactly you need?

Comment: DataTables doesn't render - `Foo Bar` in column `Name`, and `M` in column `Gender` simple as is. But I see DataTables support nested fields using dots `.`, but bot it's this case, and I'm having a lot of throuble to solve this simple thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters `[]` are specially treated when string is specified   for [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option.

You could try using function instead for [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option.

For example:

```
columns: [
    {  title: "Id", data: "id"},
    {  
        title: "Name", 
        data: function(row, type, val, meta){
           if (type === 'set') {
              row['Person[name]'] = val;
              return;
           } else {
              return row['Person[name]'];
           }
        }
    },
    {  
        title: "Gender", 
        data: function(row, type, val, meta){
           if (type === 'set') {
              row['Person[gender]'] = val;
              return;
           } else {
              return row['Person[gender]'];
           }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! For generic use I have implemented follwing: 
 `var keys = [];
 for (var i in cols) {
                if (cols[i].data !== 'id') {
                    keys[i] = cols[i].data;
                    cols[i].data = function(row, type, val, meta) {
                        if (type === 'set') {
                            row[keys[meta.col]] = val;
                        } else {
                            return row[keys[meta.col]];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }`

Comment: This saves me when I use round bracket as column name like "sum(cost)". Thanks!